# Toilet leaking into bowl. Identified part, just not its name or how to fix

Tags: plumbing, leak, toilet, overflow

After looking up several tutorials (cleaning the rubber ring in the base of the dual flush system, adjusting the overflow pipe, etc.) I've realised the problem is the water isn't shutting off when the ball is in the rest position. I was surprised when dinking about to find the water stops when the ball is half way up. After coming back a bit later, it was all the way up and the water was *still* pouring into the overflow pipe, despite me adjusting it up.

[image]

I've identified that pipe that's perpendicular to the thicker white main pipe is the issue. Or maybe the tube that comes out of it, specifically.

[image]

The thin plastic tube part seems to still be leaking out water. I'm not sure exactly which part along this chain is broken or needs replacing (and even less sure what it would be called or where to get the part in the UK)

Anyone able to offer some assistence on this issue? I'd very much like to stop wasting water literally down the drain.

Comment: I've switched the fill valve out and as far as I can tell there's no more internal leaking.
However the pipe leading into the toilet has a drip. I imagine this just needs a new washer (why they went with a fixed pipe for this I'll never understand).

Anyone able to tell me exactly what kind of washer this would need?

Answer (score 2):

The fill valve appears to be leaking. You can either replace the entire fill valve (very cheap, but a bit of effort) or if you can identify the valve type / manufacturer then you may just need to replace the washer / diaphragm. To do that you generally need to unscrew the nut that the float arm is attached to (isolate the mains water supply first, of course). Screwfix is usually a good place to source parts.

Comment: Turn off the water to the tank first to avoid a surprise bonus face wash.

Comment: With regards to fill valves, I assume it's one size fits all? Or do I need to be aware of certain types or specs or what not?

Comment: Generally fill valves are universal fitting, so you shouldn't have too much difficulty sourcing a suitable replacement